# The target entity of the relationship attribute cannot be determined on OneToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, netbeans, netbeans-7

I have the Entity class code generated by NetBeans 7.4 while creating RESTFul web services.
When I test webservice, I am getting the below exceptions

```
 The target entity of the relationship attribute [emps] on the class 
 [class test.Dept] cannot be determined.  When not using generics, ensure 
 the target entity is defined on the relationship mapping.
```

**Emp Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMP"
    ,schema="SCOTT"
)@XmlRootElement

public class Emp  implements java.io.Serializable {

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="DEPTNO")
    public Dept getDept() {
        return this.dept;
    }
```

Dept Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DEPT"
    ,schema="SCOTT"
)@XmlRootElement

public class Dept  implements java.io.Serializable {

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="dept")
    public Set getEmps() {
        return this.emps;
    }
```

**hibernate.reveng**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-schema="SCOTT"/>
  <table-filter match-name="EMP"/>
  <table-filter match-name="DEPT"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

**hibernate.cfg**

```
 <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property 
    name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <mapping class="test.Emp"/>
    <mapping class="test.Dept"/>
  </session-factory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `emps` relationship don't provide enough information to determine the target entity. You have 2 simple ways to provide this information.

#### A) Generics

Either using generics (it may implies some refactoring):

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="dept")
public Set<Emp> getEmps() {
    return this.emps;
}
```

#### B) @Target annotation

or using the `@Target` annotation (as explained in the error message) :

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="dept")
@Target(Emp.class)
public Set getEmps() {
    return this.emps;
}
```

#### C) targetEntity attribute

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="dept", targetEntity=Emp.class)
public Set getEmps() {
    return this.emps;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first approah worked very well.I tried the second approach , getting error `Emp.class is not of ElementType`

Comment: For some reason `@Target` does not work for me and [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=971549) guy. We had to use `targetEntity` attribute. Is it possible that `@Target` is valid only for `@Embedded` as indicated [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-41)?